# How do I print an exact number of characters from :text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of objects, with one attribue of `:text`. I want to print only the first 250 characters of each `:text`.

Is there any simple way in Rails to do it?

Here's how im doing my iteration:

```
-@cows.each do |c|
        %tr
          %td= c.id
          %td= c.description
          %td
```

Where, `description` is text.

Comment: so you are looking for truncate? http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`truncate`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate):

```
c.description.truncate(250, :separator => ' ')
```

It will add `"..."` automatically for you, and you have the separator option so you don't have to worry about words being chopped in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it's just normal Ruby code:

```
%td= c.description[0..249]
```

`string[n..m]` will give you a substring of `string`, starting with the `n`th element, and ending with the `m`th. see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Although perhaps you should consider whether this code might be better off in your model than in the view?